# Правильно объяснить вопрос про полиморфизм

Tags: ооп, c++

Был приведен код, и нужно было ответить, что он выведет на экран:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void someMethod() const
    { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void someMethod() const
    { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Derived o;
    Base* po = &o;
    Base bo = o;
    po->someMethod();
    bo.someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Что будет выведено на экран?
Я ответил правильно:

```
Derived
Base
```

В первом случае полиморфизм. Смотрим на объект справа и во время вызова метода определяется реальный тип объекта справа и смотрится таблица виртуальных функций. Во втором случае у нас просто объект базового класса, который ничего не знает о производном. Как правильно объяснить? Типа полизморфизм работает только на указателях? Как правильно объяснить этот момент?

Comment: Для теста, добавьте конструктор копирования в Base, и посмотрите, вызывается-ли он при Base bo = o;

Comment: Полиморфизм работает не только на указателях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прошу извинить меня за то, что вмешиваюсь после блестящего ответа уважаемого  [[@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)*хочет*кушать. Я только хотел бы сказать, что полиморфизм не может проявляться иначе, чем на указателях, поскольку базовый класс может быть и, в большинстве случаев, бывает абстрактным и, следовательно, нет возможности создать объект базового класса.
Вот классический пример полиморфизма (динамическое связывание).

В заголовочном файле:

```
class Shape{
............
public:   //или protected: 
virtual void Paint()=0;//абстрактный класс
};
class Circle : public Shape{
void Paint(){....}
};
class Rectangle : public Shape{
void Paint(){....}
};
class Square : public Shape{
void Paint(){....}
};
```

Где-то в кодах:

```
Shape *MyShapes[3];//Только так! - массив указателей на базовый класс!
MyShapes[0] = new Circle;
MyShapes[1] = new Rectangle;
MyShapes[2] = new Square;
//и затем.....
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  MyShapes[i]->Paint();//рисует каждую фигуру
```

Comment: Кстати, немного об этом классическом примере полиморфизма с `Shape`, `Square`, `Circle` и прочими. Хорошее рассуждение на тему, почему в продакшене **так делать нельзя** можно найти [**здесь.**][1]

[1]: http://insidecpp.ru/art/8/

Comment: 1. Вопрос был именно о полиморфизме и наследовании, на него и отвечали и Вы, и я.
2. Из поссыленной Вами заметки я понял лишь то, что базовый класс должен быть хорошо продуман, чтобы не обременять наследников. Если там имеются какие-то еще смыслы, разъясните их, пожалуйста. Короче, требую продолжения банкета:).

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что встрять в полемику меня подвигло лишь недоумение уважаемого @mikillskegg по поводу указателей на базовый класс.

Comment: @BuilderC Ну вопрос по указатели я тоже не до конца понял, а смысл этой статьи в том, что в нормальном `production` коде в случае, если можно заменить наследование на некоторое **свойство** объекта, то стоит поступать именно так. *Т.е конкретно этот пример с кругами, прямоугольниками и т.п оформляется с помощью одного единственного метода `Paint` и набора соответствующих точек для рисования.* А так, в учебных целях, пример, естественно, имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @BuilderC Даже, пожалуй, стоит ткнуть вам +1)

Comment: Господа, это было ни недоумение, ни возражение. Просто давно с этим не имел дело, вот и подзабыл, а тут случай подвернулся освежить знания.

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае происходит классический вызов виртуальной функции по соответствующему указателю. *Сделать то же самое, кстати говоря, можно было и с помощью ссылки:*

```
const Base& po = o;
po.someMethod();
```

---

Во втором случае будет происходит нежелательное явление под названием **срезка** / **slicing.**

Суть явления срезки заключается в том, что происходит не совсем очевидное копирование объектов, причем в данном случае копирование **только части `Base`.** Т.е во всех созданных таким образом объектах лишняя информация, которая составляет "суть" класса `Derived`, будет безвозвратно утеряна.

---

Другие примеры срезки можно изучить [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: Особенности виртуальных функций проявляются только при работе с указателями?

Comment: @mikillskegg Да, с учетом того, что на более "низком" уровне ссылка представляет собой тот же самый указатель. Сделать же вызов виртуальной функции из объекта, целиком созданного на стеке, по понятным причинам, невозможно *(то, что и происходит во втором случае в заданном вопросе)*.